# How to access application log on Confluent cloud?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-cloud

I wanted to see the broker logs on my confluent Kafka-managed cluster. I am only able to see the audit logs on Kafka, How can I be able to broker logs?

Comment: Why do you need to access the logs of the SaaS Confluent Cloud?  can you explain more details about your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to access broker logs but you can find some alternatives.

https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/faq.html#can-i-access-broker-logs